# Chidamber and Kemerer tool for metrics for other languages other than Java?

Tags: metrics

I've been trying to find a tool other than [CKJM](http://www.spinellis.gr/sw/ckjm/) for metrics that implements [Chidamber and Kemerer 1994 paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=chidamber%20and%20kemerer&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~stlauterburg/COSC425/MetricForOOD_ChidamberKemerer94.pdf&ei=O_yjT-GdC4au6AGl_vj-CA&usg=AFQjCNH-HvlBYaOUjYLXDHGqGYYlqJWxig&sig2=tEN95aKX6QSTjJtOd06zJQ), since CKJM is only for Java. I tried going on search and similar titles here but I didn't find suggestions for Chidamber and Kemeder paper or the metrics suggested were not related to it. Is there any other tool available (if possible open source / free) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ready to look at commercial tools, you can consired Project Analyzer Enterprise Edition, which calculates the Chidamber and Kemerer metrics for Visual Basic http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-ck.html

[CCCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc)  [open source] claims to be able to calculate the metrics both for C++ and for Java.

Comment: My god an answer! Thank you so much! I thought I wasn't going get it anymore :) I will make good use of this information!